# Jackson version incompatibility?

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

I'm in the process of learning REST with Spring. I am using Maven for project dependencies.

I'm using Spring 3.2.1 and Jackson to make `GET` and `POST` calls. When I use version 1.5.6 of Jackson, the `GET` works just fine and I can see the `Json` version of my object being returned from the `GET` call. However, when I upgrade to a more recent version of Jackson it no longer works and I get the following returned in the response...

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers ().

Reviewing other questions on StackOverflow there seems to be issues with the Jackson Mapper and Core versions, but I can find no other references in my project to Jackson so I don't think this is where the problem lies.

The App context contains the following...

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="im.poz.springrestserver" />
```

and the called method in the controller is as follows...

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/clients/{clientid}", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
@ResponseBody

public Client getClient(@PathVariable("clientid") int clientId) throws llegalArgumentException {
    Client client=services.retrieveClientById(clientId);
    return client;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/clients", method= RequestMethod.POST, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
public Client updateClient(@RequestBody Client client) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    client=services.updateClient(client);
    return client;

}
```

Comment: Can you include some code? Are you using the same release version for both core and mapper?

Comment: Yes, same versions. Maven seems to handle this fine and I have checked.

Comment: You didn't include the problematic POST request. However, it seems you service method accepts multiple media types. Are you selecting one of those media types on the client side, before sending the request?

Comment: Sorry, I have two problems, but for this question I am focusing on the fact that the GET stops working when I change the Jackson version. On the client side I have set 'Accept application/json' in the header, and this works fine with Jackson 1.5.6.
The other problem with the POST is probably down to my lack of experience with Spring/REST/Jackson so I need to research a little more before posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was in the build.

I'm using IntelliJ Idea 11.1 and changes to the Maven POM for the new build do not seem to be reflected in the deployed image, so changing Jackson version meant that Jackson was actually missing completely from the deployed build.

I needed to modify the artifacts and re-deploy.

Problem solved.

Comment: So you were able to use Jackson 2 and get this to work?? I continue getting this 406 error no matter what different jackson libraries I include.

Technically jackson-core is supposed to take the place of those older mapper-asl dependencies. About to ditch Spring REST and go with Resteasy or Jersey. All version 2.2.3. Can you help by telling my exactly what libraries you are using?